# How to use gem from private repository?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, github, rubygems, token

How to pull private gem on CI server?

I have rails project that uses gem from private GitHub repository, but I cannot clone it on building server.

What I found so far is https://github.com/blog/1270-easier-builds-and-deployments-using-git-over-https-and-oauth which can be perfect only if I can generate token for my `Gemfile`.

```
gem 'my_private_gem', git: 'https://MISSING_TOKEN:x-oauth-basic@github.com/USER_NAME/REPOSITORY', require: 'my_private_gem', branch: 'master'
```

So how can I generate token for that? When I'm creating GitHub application I only get `client_id` and `client_secret`.

Comment: google-fu - https://help.github.com/articles/creating-an-access-token-for-command-line-use

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, so finally I got the solution.

- Go to GitHub
- Open `Account Settings`
- Select `Applications` and then `Generate new token`
- Set this token anywhere you set environmental variables
- Add to your gemfile: `gem 'your_gem', git: "https://#{ENV['AUTH_TOKEN']}:x-oauth-basic@github.com/YourAccount/YourRepo", require: 'your_gem', branch: 'master'`

That's all!

Comment: Be careful, as your token will be exposed in the `Gemfile.lock`. If your repo is public on GitHub, you just gave the Internet a way to download all your private code.

Comment: Thanks. Simple and concise.

Comment: I think "storage" in the last line should be "[your_gem]" as well, right? I kept getting an error until I changed it to my gem's name

Comment: You can also link a private git repo using the ssh syntax in Gemfile (eg. git@gitlab.com:GROUP/PROJECT.git). You are then able to use SSH keys.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be an option for you, but if you have the ssh key of the machine registered to your Github account you can do the following in your gemfile:

`gem :your_gem, github: "your_username/your_repository"`

Comment: Yes, I'm doing it so far, but now I have CI and don't have ssh keys there.

Comment: What are you using for a CI server?

Comment: Codeship.io and Heroku for Deployment.

Comment: It looks like every project on Codeship get's an SSH key, you just have to locate it and add it to your Github account.  See: http://www.codeship.io/documentation/troubleshooting/access-to-other-repositories-fails-during-build/